# Wordpress: Change number of posts from administration

Tags: wordpress, variables

I have a problem with showposts.

```
$recent = new WP_Query('showposts=10'); while($recent->have_posts()) :
$recent->the_post();
```

and I would like to change the number of "showposts" from the administration.

I found the instruction how to create widget in /wp-admin/
but i dont know how to create a simple form to change and save number of showed posts.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under settings > reading in your wp-admin you have the configuration of how many posts will be shown in each page of your queries. You can just remove the 'showposts' parameter and the Wordpress will get the value configured in wp-admin.

Also, showposts is deprecated. You should now use 'posts_per_page' :)

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice shot André :) !

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help with 'posts_per_page', but unfortunately it 
It does not solve my problem. 
I need to create a simple form to change and save number of showed posts, but not with 'using settings > reading'. I would like to have my own widget in dashboard. I read the instructions on how to create it, but I do not know how to make the form...